# Illustrator → Layers disappearing when shifting

Tags: adobe-illustrator

While shifting the layers in **Adobe Illustrator** they disappear.
In order to better illustrate what I am saying I have done a GIF below.

[image]

What are the possible causes and how to get rid of this behavior?

Comment: Maybe you are draging a object under other object Use Ctrl + Y to see if I am right.

Comment: No sir. I am not using CTRL + Y.

Comment: You are almost certainly dragging one object under another, which is covering it.

Comment: I am just clicking over it and then dragging it.

Comment: Yes, but it's hidden under the object you dragged it to.  Press CTRL+Y to reveal the objects in Outline mode.  Change the stack order of the object, e.g. bring it to the top.

Comment: Thank, but how to accomplish this → "Change the stack order of the object, e.g. bring it to the top"

Comment: Object > Arrange > Bring to Front. Or find it in your layers, and drag it above the other layers that are covering it.  This is basic stuff in Illustrator.  Perhaps you should do some tutorials on layers and how they work.

Comment: @Billy Kerr, You taught me something new today. Thanks.

Comment: Further read https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/stacking-objects.html